# websession lost while window.location.replace or href

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, http

I lost the web session when i tried `window.location.replace("webform2.aspx")` from webform1.
I tried href as well. Also I passed "/webform2.aspx" as a paramaeter. 
However the session is lost on the redirection.
Can anyone help.

Webform1.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageload() {
            window.location.href("/webform2.aspx");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="pageload()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string str = this.Session.SessionID;
        }
```

Webform2.aspx just an empty form and having the aspx.cs as the above code to note session id by debugging.

**Update:**
I maanged to acheive using the below code. However I just keep this question open to know redirection with relative URL(without session id) lose the session. One more point here is I made cookieless as true hence only my url will have the session id.

```
 var path = window.location.href;
 var i = path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
 var loc = path.substring(0, i ).concat("webform2.aspx");  
            window.location.href(loc);
```

Comment: No,The session won't be lost.

Comment: I am receiving different session ids and also i dint see any stored data.

Comment: If you have any doubt on your code ,try to provide complete code that involved in your coding.Then only anyone can identifies root cause.you are just telling your problem here.

Comment: So you're using cookie-less session, and so your session key is stored in your URL. If you then mangle the URL and remove the session key, you lose your session. Nothing strange here.

Comment: Zruty, fine. I missed it to note and finally understood. But needed someone to confirm at the last. I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used cookieless session and hence a relative URL redirection doesnt have knowledge about session, hence a new session is initiated.

I used below code to overcome the problem.

```
var path = window.location.href;
 var i = path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
 var loc = path.substring(0, i ).concat("webform2.aspx");  
            window.location.href(loc);
```